# (property) CommandInteractionOption<CacheType>.value?: string | number | boolean Discord.js Slash command options

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord.js

I'm trying to make my first Discord Bot using typescript.
I made a simple dice roll command with a personal npm package, but there seems to be a problem with the Discord Slash command options.
I made a `sum` option that is NOT required, which sums any integer to the dice roll. But when I try to code that part, it returns these errors: 
1-`Argument of type 'string | number | boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'` 
2-`Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)`

here is my code:

```
import { Command } from "../../structures/Command";
import { inlineCode } from "@discordjs/builders";
import aimless from "aimless";

export default new Command({
    name: "roll",
    description: "Rolls a dice.",
    options: [
        {
            name: "dice",
            description: "The dice you want to roll",
            type: "STRING",
            required: true
        },
        {
            name: "sum",
            description: "The sum you want to add to your roll(s)",
            type: "INTEGER",
            required: false
        }
    ],
    run: async({ interaction }) => {
        const dice = interaction.options.get("dice").value;
        const sum = interaction.options.get("sum");
        console.log(sum)
        let rolls;

        try {
            rolls = aimless.roll(dice);
        } catch (e) {
            return interaction.followUp(`**Invalid dice! \n${inlineCode(e.toString().split(":")[2])}**`)
        }

        if (rolls.length == 1) {
            if (!sum) {
                return interaction.followUp(`**You rolled a ${inlineCode(rolls[0])}!**`);
            } else {
                return interaction.reply(`**You rolled a ${inlineCode(rolls[0])}!\n ${inlineCode(rolls[0])} + ${inlineCode(sum.value)} = ${inlineCode(+rolls[0] + +sum.value)}.**`);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The errors are in this line at `sum.value` and `+rolls[0] + +sum.value`:

```
` return interaction.reply(`**You rolled a ${inlineCode(rolls[0])}!\n ${inlineCode(rolls[0])} + ${inlineCode(sum.value)} = ${inlineCode(+rolls[0] + +sum.value)}.**`);`
```

I tried the same exact command in JavaScript with the `@discordjs/builder` "SlashCommandBuilder()" and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core problem is that `inlineCode` is expecting the value passed in to have a `string` type. However, `sum.value` can be either `string`, `number` or `boolean`, hence it could not accept due to the possibility of it being a `number` or `boolean`.

The simplest solution for your case is to wrap what you are passing into the functions inside `String` methods which will convert the values into strings before they are passed in:

```
${inlineCode(String(sum.value))}
```

and

```
inlineCode(String(+rolls[0] + +sum.value))
```

I would also advise changing `+rolls[0] + +sum.value` into `rolls[0] + sum.value` as the `+` prefix has no effect on the result of the arithmetic operation. However, I will leave this answer to adhere to the code provided in your question's example.